# Sub-sampling categories for fisher's exact test

Tags: categorical-data, fishers-exact-test, subsampling

Can I sub-sample categories before running Fisher's exact test?

I have a 50 x 22 data matrix (50 categories and 22 samples), where some sample values are < 5, so I can't run a Chi Squared test. I can run a Fisher's Exact test by simulating p values using Monte Carlo simulations on the 50 categories. I was wondering if I can instead sub sample categories and run Fisher's Exact Test on the sub-sampled categories -- bootstrapping categories instead of data essentially, and if my results would be valid if I did this.

Comment: The rule you're thinking of (not much shy of a century old these days, IIRC), is that the *expected* count should be at least 5. Not the observed count. Leaving aside commentary on the suitability of that rule of thumb, by its lights, the low observed count is not of itself dispositive. However, I wouldn't necessarily suggest mixing two different tests in any case. If you're not inclined to make them all Fisher tests, you could do the exact version of the chi-squared test conditioning on the margins (just as the Fisher test does). ...ctd

Comment: ctd ... The exact version of the chi-squared is almost trivial to do in R (see `?chisq.test`), which will randomly generate tables with the same margins as your own in order to let you sample the null distribution of the chi-squared statistic (and so obtain as accurate a p-value as you wish/have the patience to wait for). I wouldn't use the default number of simulated tables, though -- I typically look for a considerably larger number.

Comment: Thanks! Both my observed and expected distributions have values < 5. What's your take on the sub-sampling?

Comment: I don't see the point of it. Why do that?

Comment: Because rpy2 doesn't have the computational capacity to run the test when the data has 50 categories. Does sub-sampling impact the results negatively? For example, does running fisher's test on the 50 categories at once, or on subsets of the 50 categories make a difference?

Comment: Yes, naturally it makes a difference; the distribution of the test statistic changes under both the null and alternative when you remove categories.

Comment: Currently, my fisher's test rejects the null in each of the subcategories. Can I use this result to claim that it rejects the null on the main sample with all the categories?

Comment: Why not just do it in R?  `simulate=TRUE` works fine on a chi-squared test with 50 categories. It seems weird to try to invent and then justify new statistics to overcome inadequate software when working software is simple and free. ... oh, it works for Fisher's exact test as well. They both run quite fast, decent sized simulations are straightforward.

Comment: p-values from 10000 simulations of a 50x22 table with low average count takes a few seconds either way.

Comment: Because I am concerned the simulate=TRUE is not a good approach for the Fisher's test with 50 categories. Has this approach been used widely in academic publications?

Comment: 1. The test, as with the Fisher test itself, will maintain the significance level properties you seek; more specifically if you're prepared to do enough resamples it will get as close to the ordinary exact p-value of the Fisher test as you like (as you can demonstrate to yourself on any table you can run both on). How many decimal places were you going to put on the p-value in the paper? (Indeed  you can calculate a standard error on the estimate of the p-value you get, if you need reassurance, though extreme accuracy can only matter if the p-value were to come out really close to $α$) ...ctd

Comment: ctd... 2. Widely used? Of course not, 50-category tables are quite rare. You seem to be applying a much different standard on my advice than on the approach you're asking about. Has it been "widely used" with tables with 50 categories? No, of course not; indeed, I'd be mildly surprised if it had ever been used. Why the prejudice against an already justified approach in favour of one you presently have no justification for at all?

Comment: No reason -- I just don't want to use the Monte Carlo simulations with the Fisher Test. I decided to aggregate my categories in a way that was reasonable, and then applied the standard Fisher's Test. Thanks for the chat -- this helped me think through things!

Comment: While that may in the end be a better choice (assuming the choice of categories to combine were made *without reference to the interior of the table*, very important), I don't follow the reticence; in a matter of about a minute (likely less time than it took either of us to write most of our comments here) I was able to get essentially *three figure accuracy* on 50x22 Fisher-exact p-values (standard error of the p-value estimate around 0.0003) for p-values anywhere near 5%. Hence my question about how many decimal places you required -- most people don't give p-values beyond the third d.p.

Comment: Which is to say, if you had software that would compute it exactly in reasonable time and gave the p-value to three figures, nobody could tell my p-value from yours.

Comment: :) Makes sense. The thing is my data also has a non trivial amount of zeroes. It was simpler for me to explain what I was doing after combining similar categories and before computing the test of the fisher's results. I didn't understand what you meant by "(assuming the choice of categories to combine were made without reference to the interior of the table, very important)", can you elaborate? Thanks for engaging!

Comment: If you (i) didn't look at the table at all or (ii) only looked at marginal totals, when it comes time  to  choose which categories to combine, the pattern of counts in the table can't influence your choices (you're conditioning on the margins, you can see those). If you're looking at the body of the table then you're letting the observed counts influence which categories you combine, which determines your specific hypotheses (or you're giving the impression that you may have done so). This influence of data on hypothesis would impact the properties of your test.

Comment: For example, you might combine categories to put together a bunch of low-count cells (and a few higher count ones) into something with a similar pattern but a much larger marginal total. That will tend to push the p-values *down*. Or you might combine dissimilar-looking categories in order to get the individual counts up, which practice (across all possible tables) will push up your p-values - and your type II error rate along with it. Either way, your test won't behave as you need it to (and one of those choices is effectively p-hacking)

Comment: Ah, got it. Thanks for clarifying. My aggregation choices were made using an external categorization, and I made sure to only cluster similar categories. The mention of zeroes, was just what I noticed in the table, without associating these values to any specific category!

Comment: Great. Sorry, I left a sentence incomplete above, where I said "If you're looking at the body of the table then you're letting the observed counts influence which categories you combine, which determines your specific hypotheses (or you're giving the impression that you may have done so)" ... it should have finished ", it could be a problem."

Comment: :) Makes sense. Thanks a lot for engaging and for discussing this with me. I appreciate it.